# TypeError: get_weather() takes no arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm taking an online course with StackSkills for Python and have copied the code exactly as given in the lecture - we're making a weather app using Flask. I keep getting this message: TypeError: get_weather() takes no arguments (1 given)

The Python Page [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84aRm.png)

The HTML Page [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E5Dx.png)

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: don't post code as picture.

Comment: please post your code, not a picture.

Answer (score 3):

The error message explain pretty much everything.

You have a function `get_weather()` , it doesn't take any argument.
When you call it however you call it with one so the python raise you an error.

Now you have to ask yourself if you have to add an argument to your function definition or if you have to call it without any. As you need a city in `get_weather()` and as the variable city is not declared in the function, you know that you've to change the function's declaration to `def get_weather(city)`

Answer (score 1):

The function definition is incorrect. On line 10 in your Python code, change `def get_weather()` to `def get_weather(city)`.